# Duplicate entry 'P0001' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql

When I register a product, it registers, but then it does that again. I don't press nothing.

Here is the file if u want to check it..
Link: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=EL2_RR.war

THIS is the error: I know it appears because its already registered..

> "Duplicate entry 'P0001' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Here is how I call it:

```
ProductoService ser = new ProductoService();
ProductoDTO p = new ProductoDTO(codprod,fecharegistro,descripcion,tipo,stock, precio);
int ok = ser.registrarProducto(p);
```

Comment: Show your DTO Entity,

Comment: It seems that that you insert a primary key twice, did you check the query used by `ser.registrarProducto` function and try to execute it manually using the DB console?

Comment: Why can on one figure out how to indent their code to be human readable????